# all values in python list are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

Runs fine but all the time fields for each game in the games list update to the final values such as all 4 "Vic park" games all show 2145 instead of 4 separate times.

```
class Game:
    time = 0
    team1 = ""
    team2 = ""

class Field:
    def __init__(self, numTimes = 0, name = "", daysAvail = 0):
    self.numTimes = numTimes
    self.games = [Game()] * numTimes
    self.name = name
    self.daysAvail = daysAvail

fieldList = []
fieldList.append(Field(4,"Vic Park", 5)) # 5 = monday and wednesday 0000101 base 2, lsb is monday, msb sunday
fieldList[0].games[0].time = 1800
fieldList[0].games[1].time = 1915
fieldList[0].games[2].time = 2030
fieldList[0].games[3].time = 2145
fieldList.append(Field(2,"Bannerman Park", 5))
fieldList[1].games[0].time = 1800
fieldList[1].games[1].time = 1915
```

Comment: Because you create `[Game()] * numTimes` a list containing the same `Game` object `numTimes`

Comment: It is created like that during the append though isn't it? I would think the .time statements would be updating the individual list.time value for that array index not all.

Comment: Every single list index *has the same object*. Read the top linked duplicate. The `.append` is totally irrelevant

Comment: So try `fieldList[0] is fieldList[1]`